# Why wouldn't a derived object just call a redefined function in the derived class?

Tags: c++, function, class, object

Consider this situation:
Class BaseClass defines functions x() and y().   x() calls y().

Class DerivedClass inherits from BaseClass and redefines function y().

An object D of class DerivedClass is created and function x() is called.

When x() is called, which y() is used, the one defined in BaseClass or the the redefined one in DerivedClass?

Object D invokes function X() in BaseClass
Function X() invokes function Y() in BaseClass and not function Y()in DerivedClass

Function calls are bound at compile time.
This is static binding.

I am unclear why its a problem. If function X is called (by object D) and object D is of the derived class, wouldn't it be just call the D.Y() of the redefined class?

This is the sample I was given that I'm trying to make sense off.

```
baseClass
void x();   // calls y();
void y();


derivedClass
void y();

main()
derivedClass D;
D.x();
```

Comment: Can you show an example in code? It's easier to read code than to read your description of the code

Comment: I've added the code I have.

Comment: That is no c++ code - please provide a working example

Comment: You use the word "redefined" and it's not clear what you mean by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My C++ is rusty, but i'll give it a go:

Your code should have been the following

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    void x() {
        this->y();
    }

protected:
    void y() {
        /* do stuff */
    }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
protected:
    void y() {
        /* do different stuff */
    }
};


int main() {
    DerivedClass d;
    d.x();
}
```

If `y` is made virtual in its definition in `BaseClass`, then it is the overriding method `DerivedClass::y` which gets called when executing `d.x()` (where `d` is a `DerivedClass` instance).

In order to make `y` virtual, use the `virtual` keyword like so:

```
virtual void y() { /* do stuff */ }
```

If `y` is not defined using the `virtual` keyword in `BaseClass`, then it is `BaseClass::y` which gets called by `x` instead.

In order to call an overridden base class virtual method from an instance of a derived class, one must use a fully qualified method name: `d.BaseClass::y()`, which in your case would certainly not be possible without overriding `x` in `DerivedClass`.

Did I understand your problem well?

Answer (score 0):

If the object has the static type of (reference to) D, then `D::y` will be called. If it has the static type of (reference to) BaseClass, then `BaseClass:y` will be called. It's just that simple.